# How to design a database which has single category and n number of sub categories using mysql

Tags: mysql

How to design a database which has single category and n number of sub categories using mysql

Example:

**category**

**catId    categoryName**

1        cat 1

2        cat 2

3        cat 3

4        cat 4

**subcategory**

subCatId subCategoryName catId

1  subcat1                  1

2  subcat2                  1

3  subcat3                  2

4  subcat4                  4

For single category i can the above structure.

***Like this if i am having n number of subcategories. In this case how should i design the db***

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use just one table `category` with columns:

- `category_id`
- `category_name`
- `parent_category_id`

For main categories You set `parent_category_id` to null and You're done. :)

Answer (score 0):

using normalization

2 table if one subcategory has only 1 parent category

> Category
>
> > id
>
> SubCat
>
> > id
> >
> > category_id (linking to category)

you would have 3 tables if one subcategory can be part of more then 1 category. Two with your data, and one for linking the two together

> ### Category
>
> id
>
> name....
>
> ### SubCategory
>
> id
>
> name ....
>
> ### Sub_Cat_Link
>
> category_id
>
> subcategory_id

thus searching for all subcatergories of a category would result in a statment like

> select * from SubCategory where
>   category_id = idOfACategory

Answer (score 0):

My principle is that if you can support N-levels you can support 2 levels (and not get in a pickle whan a fickle business user decides to have sub-sub-categories)

So i would create a categories table with the fields

- id (autogenerated, sequence, UUID)
- parent_id (foreign key to categories.id)
- name
- ...

In order to get the children of a category a

SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = :cat_id ;

You have to be a bit careful to keep it a acyclic directed graph, i.e. not create any loops, but that's about all.